# MASQUERADE doesn't work - the response packets are lost

Tags: iptables, opensuse, vpn, nat, firewalld

According to tcpdump, the initial packet from the VPN client gets its source address translated and sent to the destination and the response packet arrives, but this response packet is just lost. I even did `firewall-cmd --set-log-denied=all`, but this very packet was lost without any log message.

Previously I had my OpenVPN server on CentOS7 without firewalld and enabled internet access for clients like this:

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
# localhost:~ # iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING -n -v
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 10 packets, 751 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    3   180 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    10.8.1.0/24          0.0.0.0/0
```

After migrating to OpenSUSE Tumbleweed I spent 4 hours trying to configure the same using firewalld, but gave up, stopped firewalld and tried to use the same iptables commands, but it still doesn't work - the response packet is silently discarded.

```
10.8.1.1 tun0 # VPN server
172.31.1.100 eth0 # WAN
```

_

```
localhost:~ # systemctl stop firewalld
localhost:~ # nft list ruleset
localhost:~ # iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.8.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
localhost:~ # nft list ruleset
localhost:~ # iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Oct 15 02:39:41 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Oct 15 02:39:41 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Oct 15 02:39:41 2021
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [8078:12476730]
:INPUT ACCEPT [7999:12471990]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [29:1740]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7524:1618476]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [7553:1620216]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Oct 15 02:39:41 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Oct 15 02:39:41 2021
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [8078:12476730]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7524:1618476]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Oct 15 02:39:41 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Oct 15 02:39:41 2021
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [7999:12471990]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [29:1740]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7524:1618476]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Oct 15 02:39:41 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Oct 15 02:39:41 2021
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [7999:12471990]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [29:1740]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7524:1618476]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Oct 15 02:39:41 2021
```

The client trying to connect to SMTP

```
localhost:~ # tcpdump -nn -i any "port 465 or icmp"
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
02:41:25.326501 tun0  In  IP 10.8.1.32.37346 > 173.194.222.16.465: Flags [S], seq 3151810436, win 64240, options [mss 1286,sackOK,TS val 1758001736 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
02:41:25.326590 eth0  Out IP 172.31.1.100.37346 > 173.194.222.16.465: Flags [S], seq 3151810436, win 64240, options [mss 1286,sackOK,TS val 1758001736 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
02:41:25.363047 eth0  In  IP 173.194.222.16.465 > 172.31.1.100.37346: Flags [S.], seq 1158840380, ack 3151810437, win 65535, options [mss 1430,sackOK,TS val 4105615202 ecr 1758001736,nop,wscale 8], length 0
02:41:26.280346 tun0  In  IP 10.8.1.32.37346 > 173.194.222.16.465: Flags [S], seq 3151810436, win 64240, options [mss 1286,sackOK,TS val 1758002755 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
02:41:26.280400 eth0  Out IP 172.31.1.100.37346 > 173.194.222.16.465: Flags [S], seq 3151810436, win 64240, options [mss 1286,sackOK,TS val 1758002755 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
02:41:26.316940 eth0  In  IP 173.194.222.16.465 > 172.31.1.100.37346: Flags [S.], seq 1158840380, ack 3151810437, win 65535, options [mss 1430,sackOK,TS val 4105616156 ecr 1758001736,nop,wscale 8], length 0
02:41:27.331029 eth0  In  IP 173.194.222.16.465 > 172.31.1.100.37346: Flags [S.], seq 1158840380, ack 3151810437, win 65535, options [mss 1430,sackOK,TS val 4105617170 ecr 1758001736,nop,wscale 8], length 0
02:41:28.306349 tun0  In  IP 10.8.1.32.37346 > 173.194.222.16.465: Flags [S], seq 3151810436, win 64240, options [mss 1286,sackOK,TS val 1758004782 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
02:41:28.306380 eth0  Out IP 172.31.1.100.37346 > 173.194.222.16.465: Flags [S], seq 3151810436, win 64240, options [mss 1286,sackOK,TS val 1758004782 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
02:41:28.342862 eth0  In  IP 173.194.222.16.465 > 172.31.1.100.37346: Flags [S.], seq 1158840380, ack 3151810437, win 65535, options [mss 1430,sackOK,TS val 4105618182 ecr 1758001736,nop,wscale 8], length 0
02:41:30.403068 eth0  In  IP 173.194.222.16.465 > 172.31.1.100.37346: Flags [S.], seq 1158840380, ack 3151810437, win 65535, options [mss 1430,sackOK,TS val 4105620242 ecr 1758001736,nop,wscale 8], length 0
^C
11 packets captured
13 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: To be sure there's no route problem that can't be seen with current information, would you add the result of this in the question: `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route`?

Comment: The response packets are processed in `conntrack`, the kernel connection tracker. If you switched OS, you also switched kernels, so make sure `conntrack` is enabled and loaded (if a module). Compare kernel configuration for your two OS in case you need to change it on OpenSUSE.

Comment: @dirkt In traffic gets SNAT-ed (1st and 2nd lines of tcpdump). So there's something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I decided to reboot, but before reboot I dumped the runtime kernel parameters to a file and afterwards repeated the `iptables/sysctl` setup and this time it worked!

After comparing sysctl output I see that `net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding` was 0 even though `net.ipv4.ip_forward` was 1. I didn't know that forwarding could be enabled or disabled for a single network card. Looks like playing with `firewall-cmd` set the wrong value for the runtime kernel parameter and `firewall-cmd` was unable to revert it for some reason.